# Delete XML record on the click of button using AJAX in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ajax, xml

Hi I'm trying to delete the record from XML file which is showing data in the form of table using AngularJS my code is:

XML file

```
<UserDetail>
  <Detail>
    <EmployeeID>124578</EmployeeID>
    <EmployeeName>suresh</EmployeeName>
    <EmailID>suresh@xyz.com</EmailID>
  </Detail>
  <Detail>
    <EmployeeID>587458</EmployeeID>
    <EmployeeName>Namit</EmployeeName>
    <EmailID>Namit@xyz.com</EmailID>
  </Detail>
</UserDetail>
```

Here is my AngularJS code with that I m get changing XML to JSON and present in the form of table

```
<script>
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
            $http.get('myDB.xml')
            .then(function (response) {
                var x2js = new X2JS();
                $scope.details = [];
                var data = x2js.xml_str2json(response.data);
                $scope.details = data.UserDetail.Detail;
                $scope.getID = function (id) {                 
                    var index = 0
                    $scope.details.splice(index, 1);
                }
            });

        });
      </script>
```

HTML code with that my data coming in table format

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
            <table border="1" width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <th>Employee ID</th>
                    <th>Employee Name</th>
                    <th>Email ID</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                </tr>
                <tr ng-repeat="detail in details" align="center">
                    <td>{{detail.EmployeeID}}</td>
                    <td>{{detail.EmployeeName}}</td>
                    <td>{{detail.EmailID}}</td>
                    <td>
                        <button ng-click="getID(detail.EmployeeID)" class="btnDelete">Delete Request</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
```

Please help me to delete record form XML file on the click of button using ajax in angularJS

Comment: Why don't you do it serverside? or better to make a call to a script which responds as json instead.

Comment: @Jai I tried with ASP.net but in that i m unable to refer the id with that button can knows that which record i want to delete see my code <asp:Button CssClass="btnDelete" Text="Delete Request" runat="server" ng-click="getID(detail.EmployeeID)" OnClick="btnDelete_Click"/>    protected void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string id = "";
        var xDoc = XDocument.Load(@"D:\test\myDB.xml");
        xDoc.Descendants("Detail")
           .Elements("EmployeeID")
           .Where(x => x.Value == id)
           .Remove();
        xDoc.Save(@"path.xml");
    }

Answer (score 0):

You may need to convert the `xml to json again` and then delete the object.

```
{
  "UserDetail": {
    "Detail": [
      {
        "EmployeeID": "124578",
        "EmployeeName": "suresh",
        "EmailID": "suresh@xyz.com"
      },
      {
        "EmployeeID": "587458",
        "EmployeeName": "Namit",
        "EmailID": "Namit@xyz.com"
      }
    ]
  }
}

$scope.getID = function (emp) {                 
   var jsondata = x2js.xml_str2json(xml); //Its an array of object hopefully
   var index = jsondata.map(function(item) { return item.id; })
                   .indexOf(emp.EmployeeID);

   jsondata.splice(removeIndex, 1); // your json here... 
            which you can convert it back to xml and update. 
}
```